# ContentProvider, passing originating ContentObserver in when calling the notifyXXX methods

Tags: android, android-contentprovider

When I implement a custom ContentProvider, I want notifications to work, so I call getContext().getContentResolver().notifyChange(uri, null); at the end of, say, the update method. The second parameter is the ContentObserver that originated the change, seems important for the self-notification mechanism to work. However, all snippets I've found so far always pass null there. How is this supposed to work?